# When should a thread generally yield?

Tags: multithreading, language-agnostic

In most languages/frameworks, there exists a way for a thread to yield control to other threads.  However, I can't really think of a time when yielding from a thread was the correct solution to a given problem.  When, in general, should one use `Thread.yield()`, `sleep(0)`, etc?

Comment: If your OS supports pre-emptive multitasking, then explicit calls to `yield()` should never be necessary, because the scheduler should automatically take care of all context-switching decisions for you.  (if you feel the impulse to call `yield()` anyway, that may be an indication that your blocking/scheduling algorithms are in need of improvement, i.e. there is another, better way to achieve the goal you're trying to achieve)

Answer (score 6):

One use case could be for testing concurrent programs, try to find interleavings that reveal flaws in your synchronization patterns. For instance in Java:

> A useful trick for increasing the number of interleavings, and
>   therefore more effectively exploring the state space of your programs,
>   is to **use `Thread.yield` to encourage more context switches during
>   operations that access shared state**. (The effectiveness of this
>   technique is platform-specific, since the JVM is free to treat
>   THRead.yield as a no-op [JLS 17.9]; using a short but nonzero sleep
>   would be slower but more reliable.) — [JCIP](http://jcip.net/)

Also interesting from the Java point of view is that their semantics are not defined:

> **The semantics of `Thread.yield` (and `Thread.sleep(0)`) are undefined
>   [JLS 17.9]; the JVM is free to implement them as no-ops or treat them
>   as scheduling hints.** In particular, they are not required to have the
>   semantics of sleep(0) on Unix systemsput the current thread at the end
>   of the run queue for that priority, yielding to other threads of the
>   same prioritythough some JVMs implement yield in this way. — [JCIP](http://jcip.net/)

This makes them, of course, rather unreliable. This is very Java specific, however, in generally I believe following is true:

Both are low-level mechanism which *can* be used to influence the **scheduling order**. If this is used  to achieve a certain functionality then this functionality is based on the probability of the OS scheduler which seems a rather bad idea. This should be managed by higher-level synchronization constructs instead.

For testing purpose or for forcing the program into a certain state it seems a handy tool.

Comment: Back when I used to write multi-threaded kernels atop single-tasking systems, I had a debugging tool to control the timeslice duration for exactly this purpose.  It's amazing how much supposedly-thread-safe code will crash when you force a preemptive undispatch every few machine instructions.  Nothing useful gets done at that rate, but you sure do find the bugs!

Comment: @RossPatterson Great to hear about that in practice.

Answer (score 3):

> When, in general, should one use Thread.yield(), sleep(0), etc?

It depends on the VM are thread model we are talking about.  For me the answer is *rarely if ever*.

Traditionally some thread models were non-preemptive and others are (or were) not mature hence the need for `Thread.yield()`.

I feel that `Thread.yield()` is like using `register` in C.  We used to rely on it to improve the performance of our programs because in many cases the programmer was better at this than the compiler.  But modern compilers are *much* smarter and in much fewer cases these days can the programmer actually improve the performance of a program with the use of `register` and `Thread.yield()`.

Answer (score 2):

Keep your OS scheduler decide for you ?

So never yield, and never sleep(0) until you match a case where sleep(0) is absolutly necessary and document it here.

Also context switch are costy so I don't think a lot of people want more context switches.

Comment: 'So never yield, and never sleep(0) until you match a case where sleep(0) is absolutly necessary and document it here.' - OH CAN WE HAVE BABIES TOGETHER? (I am male).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but you didn't get any good answers here.

In general yielding is a way to be polite to other threads/processes and give them a chance to run on the same CPU with minimal delay to the yielding thread.

Not all yielding is equal either. On Windows SwitchToThread() only releases CPU if another thread is scheduled to run *on the same CPU* which means it very possibly will simply resume the calling thread while Sleep(0) has looser scheduler semantics (until Windows Vista, Sleep(0) would only yield to threads of equal or higher priority); on Linux sched_yield() is similar to Sleep(0) while nanosleep() with a 0 timespec seemingly marks the thread as unready for whatever period the timer slack is set to (inferred from profiling and substantiated [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/482168/) ). Behavior on MacOS is seemingly similar to Linux, but with much less timer slack - haven't looked into it that much though.

Yielding was way more useful in the days when uniprocessor systems were abundant because it really helped keep the system moving, but for example on Windows where by default Sleep(1) is actually predictably at least a 15.6ms delay (note that this is nearly an entire frame at 60fps if you're making a game or media player or something) it's still pretty valid although MessageWaitForMultipleObjectsEx should be preferred in general UI applications. Windows 10 added a new type of high resolution waitable timer with microsecond granularity that should probably be preferred over other methods, so hopefully that kind of yielding won't be so necessary anymore either.

In the context of N:1 and N:M cooperative threading models (not common at the OS level anymore, but still employed at the application-level through libraries providing Fibers and Coroutines often enough) yielding is still also definitely useful to keep things moving.

Unfortunately it's also abused pretty often, for example yielding in a busy loop rather than waiting on a synchronization primitive because the appropriate primitive isn't obvious or because the developer is overly optimistic about how long their threads will wait for / overly pessimistic about the scheduler. But in practice on most modern multitasking OSes unless the system is extremely busy, threads waiting on a synchronization primitive will get run almost instantly when the primitive is triggered/released/whatever.

You should try to avoid yielding, especially as an alternative to using a proper synchronization method. When you do need to yield, a zero sleep or waiting on a high resolution time source is probably better than a normal yield - I call the prior a "long yield" as opposed to a "short yield" - but unless you're using the system interface the implementation of sleep in your programming language/framework of choice might "optimize" sleep(0) into a short yield or even a no-op for you, sadly.