# Is the description written for thread.yield is correct?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a little doubt regarding Yield's definition:

In the java docs. Yield is described as :

```
public static void [yield][1]()
```

> A hint to the scheduler that the current thread is willing to yield
>   its current use of a 
>       processor. The scheduler is free to ignore this hint.

And it means that current thread is not pausing temporarily. It is just indicating to scheduler. Now it is upto the scheduler to decide if he want to stop the execution of thread or not.Right?

And here at this link, it is written that on yield, thread will be definitely suspended.

```
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/thread_yield.htm
```

Can someone explain it?

Comment: I would generally take the JavaDoc as more accurate than someone else's tutorial.

Comment: Are you trying to suspend for some amount of time? If so, you probably want Thread.sleep instead.

Comment: Also, see this question for some good answers about what `yield` does, or more specifically, *doesn't* do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654532/when-should-a-thread-generally-yield

Answer (score 3):

> And it means that current thread is not pausing temporarily. It is just indicating to scheduler. Now it is upto the scheduler to decide if he want to stop the execution of thread or not.  Right?

Right!

If the javadoc says that, then it is correct.  The javadoc is *definitive*.  It is saying that an implementation is *permitted* to ignore the `yield`.  Even if every Java implementation that you found didn't do that, the javadoc says that a new implementation *is allowed to* do it.

And in fact, it is quite reasonable for the thread scheduler to ignore the `yield` if there is nothing else in the system that is ready to be scheduled.

> And here at this link, it is written that on yield, thread will be definitely suspended.

That linked page is incorrect.  Plain and simple.

---

If you want the thread to definitely pause, call `sleep(...)` with an argument greater than zero.  The javadoc says:

> *"Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the specified number of milliseconds, subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers."*

The latter means that you can't accurately predict *how long* the thread will sleep ... but it will sleep.  (In reality, it is unlikely that the thread will sleep for less time than the argument specified ...)

Answer (score 0):

Thread.yield is a native method which invokes a system function if any, eg Windows SwitchToThread function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686352(v=vs.85).aspx, there you can know the exact behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In a preemptive scheduling OS (like all modern OSs), yielding is a request to the operating system to yield.  You cannot force the operating system to run another thread in java or any other userspace code, you are always at the mercy of the scheduler.  It is free to re-schedule you instantly, without skipping a beat.  This is actually part of what makes lockfree algorithms so interesting: even if the scheduler is pathological, they keep working.

That being said, OSs understand that, if you yield(), you really intended it, so they tend to actually switch threads.